# Cannot generate public key from pem with RSA

Tags: encryption, rust, cryptography, rsa

I need to generate a public key using a pem that was sent over tcp to verify a message. I am using the function `RsaPublicKey::from_public_key_pem(public_pem)` I am using the rsa crate

public_pem is a string that consists of:

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAo4gBUOV0d9DMzor8aM3b\n82clrpEhoTaXBLpizioiEsNJF/xxNE9mzQkmJ1GCzToTJCHBFz7SzOCFEHjSpGfh\noz1I6zGQF5jSwNDOqbbMYeA77VqwV8iCIWXqn1aQ5ZCnOUQ0a3OqZ/aSwW2YE01X\nfXEAHzTEzplzM2Kh5t3WxjKMwtwRmJsFZBMJch206EkSGMpwJGaXstZXeVYlh5wZ\nLVX+XMAdtpeH16S5jBxW/OsJFbU6szTdtbzjA0bp73WhidT7IUOp4IQJHte7+TIU\nWfcyFnDfQCTiLmGaQQuqscZ/Q2FAAKCFhpN41/usYrL/q18kf2zkmtGFEb+pLrhd\nawIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n

When I pass this into from_public_key_pem it results in this error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Asn1(Error { kind: Pem(Label), position: None })'
```

Comment: Is that exactly how your PEM string is formatted? It looks like it has 2 `\n` characters between the `BEGIN PUBLIC KEY` part and the rest of it.

Comment: There are more, Jeremy, look at the start. But I am wondering if these are *actual* `\n` characters or that they indeed represent CRLF, which they should. Maybe the decoder is expecting a carriage return as well.

Comment: @JeremyMeadows If you're talking about how PUBLIC and KEY are on different lines that is just because of stackoverflow formatting it werid. But everything else is exactly how the RSA crate formatted it when I convertted the public key into a pem and sent it.

Comment: Otherwise the [encoding looks OK to me](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAo4gBUOV0d9DMzor8aM3b82clrpEhoTaXBLpizioiEsNJF_xxNE9mzQkmJ1GCzToTJCHBFz7SzOCFEHjSpGfhoz1I6zGQF5jSwNDOqbbMYeA77VqwV8iCIWXqn1aQ5ZCnOUQ0a3OqZ_aSwW2YE01XfXEAHzTEzplzM2Kh5t3WxjKMwtwRmJsFZBMJch206EkSGMpwJGaXstZXeVYlh5wZLVX-XMAdtpeH16S5jBxW_OsJFbU6szTdtbzjA0bp73WhidT7IUOp4IQJHte7-TIUWfcyFnDfQCTiLmGaQQuqscZ_Q2FAAKCFhpN41_usYrL_q18kf2zkmtGFEb-pLrhdawIDAQAB) at first glance.

Comment: @YungOne yeah, my bad. it looks like it is just word wrapping and wasn't actually an inserted character :(

Comment: Again, are there **actual backslash characters** in the string you try to decode? I think it is silly to keep debugging if you cannot answer that.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yes there are because that's how the RSA crate outputs the pem once you convert your public key